# nested ruby params hash and radio buttons dont play along well

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, radio-button, nested, parameters

In a Form, i want users to add one or many Answers on a single submit. To achieve this, i have a params hash containing an array of hashes. An example would look like this:

```
screen[question][unique_answer][][text]
screen[question][unique_answer][][next_screen]
```

and the expected hash should be something like:

```
{
...
"unique_answer" => [ { "text"=>"positive answer", "next_screen"=>"no_link" }, { "text" => "negative answer", "next_screen"=>"5" } ]
...
}
```

the Answer is a fieldset containing an text input and some radio inputs. The user can add a new Answer; this is done via javascript (it copies the fieldset, changes the ids so they don't collide and adds it to the DOM).

I have successfully used this technique several times before with fieldsets which only have text inputs, but now, when radio buttons are included,  the browser take all of the radiobuttons as if they were the same group and allows only to check one trough the whole answers.

Moreover, the submitted params includes the key "next_screen" only on the first array object. it looks like this:

```
{
...
"unique_answer" => [ { "text"=>"positive answer", "next_screen"=>"no_link" }, { "text" => "negative answer" } ]
...
}
```

an extract of the html form follows:

```
<fieldset class="answer">
    <ol>
        <li id="screen_question_unique_answer_answer_text_input" class="unique-answer--answer string input required stringish">
            <label for="screen_question_unique_answer_answer_text" class=" label">Answer text</label>
            <input type="text" name="screen[question][unique_answer][][text]" id="screen_question_unique_answer_answer_text">
        </li>

        <li id="screen_question_unique_answer__next_screen_input" class="unique-answer--answer next_screen_picker radio input required">
            <fieldset class="choices">
                <legend class="label">
                    <label>Next Screen</label>
                </legend>
                <ol class="choices-group">
                    <li class="choice">
                        <label for="screen_question_unique_answer__next_screen_5">
                            <input type="radio" value="5" name="screen[question][unique_answer][][next_screen]" id="screen_question_unique_answer__next_screen_5">Blanditiis necessitatibus aliquam recusandae doloremque suscipit.
                        </label>
                    </li>
                    <li class="choice">
                        <label for="screen_question_unique_answer__next_screen_no_link">
                            <input type="radio" value="no_link" name="screen[question][unique_answer][][next_screen]" id="screen_question_unique_answer__next_screen_no_link">Back to Inbox
                        </label>
                    </li>
                </ol>
            </fieldset>
        </li>
    </ol>
</fieldset>

<fieldset class="answer">
    <ol>
        <li id="screen_question_unique_answer_1_answer_text_input" class="unique-answer--answer string input required stringish">
            <label for="screen_question_unique_answer_1_answer_text" class=" label">Answer text</label>
            <input type="text" name="screen[question][unique_answer][][text]" id="screen_question_unique_answer_1_answer_text">
        </li>

        <li id="screen_question_unique_answer_1_next_screen_input" class="unique-answer--answer next_screen_picker radio input required">
            <fieldset class="choices">
                <legend class="label">
                    <label>Next Screen</label>
                </legend>
                <ol class="choices-group">
                    <li class="choice">
                        <label for="screen_question_unique_answer_1_next_screen_5">
                            <input type="radio" value="5" name="screen[question][unique_answer][][next_screen]" id="screen_question_unique_answer_1_next_screen_5">Blanditiis necessitatibus aliquam recusandae doloremque suscipit.
                        </label>
                    </li>
                    <li class="choice">
                        <label for="screen_question_unique_answer_1_next_screen_no_link">
                            <input type="radio" value="no_link" name="screen[question][unique_answer][][next_screen]" id="screen_question_unique_answer_1_next_screen_no_link">Back to Inbox
                        </label>
                    </li>
                </ol>
            </fieldset>
        </li>
    </ol>
</fieldset>
```

Does anyone had this problem? Any comments on how to solve this?

Comment: Well since all your radio buttons have the same ´name´, they are technically one group. After all, that's what defines a radio group. Use different names for each answer and you should be good.

Comment: i understand your comment and for sure it would work, but what im interested in is using the rails behaviour of nested params hash so that i have an array of N answers. further reading [link](http://surrealdetective.github.io/blog/2013/07/01/the-nested-ruby-params-hash-for-complex-html-forms-and-sinatra/)

Comment: True. You could augment the naming with an index of the question, resulting in radio names like ´screen[question][unique_answer][1][next_screen]´ which will result in your ´unique_answer´ array turning into a hash while your browser is happy with the different radio button names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after hitting the wall several times i ended up following KappaNossi advice and added an index to the params., so now the hash looks like this

```
screen[question][unique_answer][1][next_screen]
```

Altought this doesnt sound like much of a work, all other form fields were working nicely with the technique described above and had indeed to write an specific implementation for this case.